# Rails: How to fix the ActionView::MissingTemplate error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error:

```
Started POST "/submitEmailAddress" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-13 15:29:26 +0100
Processing by OnepagerController#submitEmailAddress as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "email"=>"testing@this.com", "commit"=>"OK, LET'S GO!"}
submitEmailAddress
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template onepager/submitEmailAddress, application/submitEmailAddress with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
  * "/Users/ola/Documents/RailsApps/newwp/app/views"
  * "/Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/videojs_rails-4.6.1/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/onepager_controller.rb:22:in `submitEmailAddress'


  Rendered /Users/ola/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/missing_template.text.erb (0.3ms)
```

When I try to submit an email with this form:

(inside **index.html.erb**)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <%= bootstrap_form_tag url: '/submitEmailAddress', remote: true, html: {class: 'emailForm'} do |f| %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, hide_label: true %>
        <%= f.submit "OK, LET'S GO!"%>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my method:

(inside **onepager_controller.rb**)

```
def submitEmailAddress
    puts "inside submitEmailAddress"

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to root_path}
        format.js
    end
end
```

And this is my routes:

(from my **routes.rb**)

```
root 'onepager#index'
post 'submitEmailAddress', to: 'onepager#submitEmailAddress'
```

Any idea of how I can fix this error?

Comment: Do exists onepager/submitEmailAddress template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a view template at either `app/views/onepager/submitEmailAddress.js.erb`.

Since your controller has a redirect for the HTML format, you don't need the `app/views/onepager/submitEmailAddress.html.erb`, but if you ever removed that redirect, or wanted to support browsers without JavaScript, you'd want the HTML template as well.

Comment: I just removed the `format.js` from the `respond_to`, and now it works. Is this a problem (that I don't have the `format.js` inside the `respond_to`, why should it be there? Will it be a problem to just have `format.html {redirect_to root_path}` in the `respond_to`?).

Comment: It will be there if you scaffolded the controller, as scaffolding by default assumes you have both HTML views and JS views (for an API).  If you don't plan on having an AJAX response or an API for this route, then removing it is fine.  As for the `format.html`, so long as you perform the `redirect_to` in the block after it, you don't need an HTML page for this route either.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller action has `format.js` as a response, which should render `app/views/onepager/submitEmailAddress.js.erb`. That template does not exist. You should either create it or have a different response.

The simplest response would be `format.js { render nothing: true }`, but you need  to decide what is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `remote: true` in your  form or create`app/views/onepager/submitEmailAddress.js.erb`